# captcha does not work on yii

Tags: php, yii, captcha

User model:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        ...
        array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'on'=>'register'),
        ...
    );
}
```

UserController

```
public function actionRegister()
{
    $model=new User;
    if(isset($_POST['User']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['User'];
        if($model->save()){
             $this->redirect(array('login'));
        }
    }
    ...
    $this->render('register');
}
```

View - register.php

```
<?php $this->widget('CCaptcha'); ?>
            <div class="captcha"><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField( $model,'verifyCode', array('class'=>'captcha')); ?></div>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
```

This renders the captcha alright but the validation does not happen. What could be the problem?

Comment: You should probably specify framework.

Comment: I am using Yii Framework as already mentioned in the title of the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think your problem is with on=>register try 'on'=>'insert' and  read

[http://yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/25817-rules-models/](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/25817-rules-models/)

and

http://php-thoughts.cubedwater.com/2009/validation-scenarios/

and

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/13572-how-to-define-scenarios/

Comment: I had not pasted the entire code earlier for brevity. Of course there was a `render` function call afterwards, else the captcha won't have been rendered in the first place. I have updated my code accordingly

Comment: what happen when you use $model->validate()  instead of $model->save()?

Comment: Returns true all the time even if I have provided a wrong captcha